# How to make a reusable component with proper, testable event handlers in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, reactjs

Say you want a React component that "raises a custom event", like this checkbox (here in CoffeeScript):

```
CustomCheckbox = React.createClass
  displayName: "Checkbox"

  getDefaultProps: -> 
    onCheckedChange: () ->

  render: -> 
    <div className="parent">
        <div className={className} onClick={@onClick}></div>
    </div>

  onClick: -> 
    @props.onCheckedChange(); // call the given event handler directly
```

Now I want to write a test that uses the component and simulate the event:

```
describe 'SomeOtherComponentThatUsesACheckbox', ->
  it "some other component that uses a checkbox handles onCheckedChanged", ->
    isChecked = false
    handler = () -> isChecked = true

    checkbox = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
      <CustomCheckbox onCheckedChange={handler} />
    );

    ReactTestUtils.Simulate.checkedChange(checkbox)

    isChecked.should.be.equal true
```

This won't work. There's no checkedChange on simulate, and if there was it would only emit an event that no one listens to, as the onCheckedChange handler is not hooked up to anything, but just invoked directly. And maybe it's not supposed to work.

But the questions are:

How do I write the CustomCheckbox so that it raises and subscribes to events in the same way React's own components, like `<div>` and `<a>` do?

Can I write the CustomCheckbox so I can use ReactTestUtils to simulate the checkedChanged event?

If not, how is a component using other reusable components supposed to be tested without knowing the internals of the reusable component?

**UPDATE**

I've updated the question a tiny bit to be more specific to the problem. I've added a little more complexity to the html generated by the component. The problem is more precisely: How can I simulate events without knowing the internals of a complex component?

Answer (score 2):

You're not firing a custom event. Your event is a click event, and your handler is an `onClick` handler, so using `simulate.click` should work.

If you want to make sure that the `checkedChange` handler is called when the click event happens, you should pass a mock handler in your test and spy on it. I don't know what the syntax would be in coffeescript, but something like this:

```
describe 'SomeOtherComponentThatUsesACheckbox',
  -> it "some other component that uses a checkbox handles onCheckedChanged", -> isChecked = false
  handler = () -> jasmine.createSpy()
      checkbox = ReactTestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
        <CustomCheckbox onCheckedChange={handler} />
      );
  ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(checkbox) 
  expect(handler).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

You can unit test the custom check box component to see that `isChecked` actually changes too, but its using the `onClick` event, not another event.

Also, you can pass the handler as an `onClick` handler in the props, and then its obvious from outside that the click event triggers it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have tried to simulate a click on the checkbox, but it does not work? It only works if I the `div` directly. In other words: If I change my line from `ReactTestUtils.Simulate.checkedChange(checkbox)` to `ReactTestUtils.Simulate.click(checkbox)` as I understand your suggestion, then it does not work. Am I misunderstanding you? The spy thing I'm fine with, I just used a simpler approach for assertion in my sample :)

Comment: I've updated the question a tiny bit to be more specific to the problem. I've added a little more complexity to the html generated by the component. The problem is more precisely: How can I simulate events without knowing the internals of a complex component?

Comment: You need to document which params/events it supports. You can't do it otherwise.

You need to create an 'API' for your reusable component

Comment: Ok. I kind of hoped that documenting which custom events it could emit would be enough. But it makes sense. I'm not sure what you mean by params? Properties? If I understand you correctly, I would have to make a ref name on the inner div to find it and click it? And I should document that the component has such a ref and it is clickable as part of it's public api?

Comment: By params I meant props. Regarding the ref- no! You do not want to document that, and you dont need to even use a ref. The onclick should reach the inner html elements because thats how events work in the DOM, natively. The point is that youre giving a 'black-box' solution to something, which supports specific props (its API), and will always have a given behavior. What the component does inside is of no interest to anyone else, and can actually be detrimental to their use of the component- they may rely on the specific implementation, which is subject to change.

Comment: I believe in TDD, so optimally you would write your test first (which will fail) and then implement the component (test should now pass), breaking this up into small red-green test-code-refactor cycles until it is complete.  If you were to write this TDD, you would not even dream of exposing the implementation, since it would not matter.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply, but I think we're talking past each other. What you're stating, is exactly my problem, not the solution :) 
(continued...)

Comment: (...continued) I need to know which inner element to click, and thus I already know too much about the internals. I can't click on the component as such. So how will you then click the component without knowing which html element to aim for? I don't believe that can be done, and that is why my question was phrased as a need to trigger custom events that could be simulated the way the "native" events are... I believe now that the best way to do it in tests is to invoke the `onClick()`directly from the test to "simulate" a click.